# Limit the text in the div, but make the whole div clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this `styled-select` which I made for my requirements. Now the problem is that if the selected option is larger than the whole area, naturally it will fill the whole `div` as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Now I want it to be limited or have a margin on the right, in order to show the arrow which I used as `background: url`, like the picture below:

[image]

If I decrease the width of the `div` it will be ok, but the problem is that it won't be clickable in order to open the dropdown menu. Now I want to know if there is a solution to limit the text but still have the clickable area as well?

**Here is my code:**
[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/qyf22h83/10/)

```js
$(function() {

   $('.styled-select select').hide();
   $("select#elem").val('0');

   $('.styled-select div').each(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $(this).html($container.find('select option:selected').text());
   });

   $('.styled-select div').click(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var opLen = $container.find('select').children('option').length;
     if (opLen < 5) {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', opLen).focus();
     } else {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', 5).focus();
     }
   });

   $('.styled-select select').click(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var text = $container.find('select option:selected').text();
     $container.find('div').html(text);
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

   $('.styled-select select').focusout(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

 });
```

```css
.styled-select select {
   position: absolute;
   background: transparent;
   width: 420px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   color: black;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 4;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -o-appearance: none;
   z-index: 1;
   outline: none;
   top: 42px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
 }
 
 .styled-select {
   background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/f5gjjtswd/campaign_Selector.png') no-repeat right;
   background-color: white;
   width: 420px;
   height: 42px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
   background-position: 97% 50%;
 }
 
 .styled-select option {
   font-size: 18px;
   background-color: white;
   margin-left: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="styled-select" style="width: 301px; margin:5px 0 0 10px;">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div id="userChannelDivId" style="font-size:18px; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 5px; width: 295px; height: 42px; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden"></div>
  <select id="userChannelId" name="userChannelId" style="width:100%">
    <option value="">resh resh reshadreshadreshadreshadreshad resh</option>
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Celect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Delect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Felect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Gelect ---</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted the **non-working** code, so we could see what you did wrong and need to fix.

Comment: @Barmar the working-code is not working as expected. My expected behaviour is the one with limited text area

Comment: You would have better to post more relevant picture of expected behaviour because a white arrow over a white background doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @reshad What I mean is you should post the code that has the margin you want, but where clicking doesn't work. Then someone can show you how to make clicking work.

Comment: @A.Wolff The expected behaviour is that the text goes under the arrow, in order to be clickable

Comment: @Barmar Ah ok ! now I will edit the porst. Thanks

Comment: @reshad But you aware your arrow is not visible, right?

Comment: @A.Wolff I got the answer, thanks a lot. scott and eithedog answered below

Comment: While you already have an answer, I would also recommend the following changes: Instead of an absolute position to the div, just set the `line-height` to the height you want (42px), and add padding to the left and right to fit your design. Absolute positioning is expensive to render too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changes to the `#UserChannelDivID`...

```
width: 265px;
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
padding: 0 30px 0 0;
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyf22h83/14/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the `div` and then apply a transparent border that will extend the container over the tick.

As such:

```
#userChannelDivId {
  width: 250px !important;
  border-right: 45px solid transparent;
}
```

does the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/qyf22h83/13/

Comment: Perfect ! that works fine. In 3 minutes I will select it as the correct answer. Thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, The answer of @Scott was a bit better. again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Only Solution**

Based on [select-css](https://github.com/filamentgroup/select-css) Github repo, here is a CSS-only solution. No need for fancy JavaScript when the HTML `select` tag provides all the functionality. This solution replaces the drop-down arrow. Wrap select in `custom-select` div and add the CSS. Replace the drop-down arrow definition with your own.

https://jsfiddle.net/sacwebdeveloper/ctchr3ph/

```css
/* Container used for styling the custom select, the buttom class below adds the
 * bg gradient, corners, etc. */
.custom-select {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

/* This is the native select, we're making everything but the text invisible so
 * we can see the button styles in the wrapper */
.custom-select select {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 outline: none;
 padding: .6em .8em .5em .8em;
  
 /* Prefixed box-sizing rules necessary for older browsers */
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;

 /* Font size must be 16px to prevent iOS page zoom on focus */
 font-size: 16px;
}


/* Custom arrow sits on top of the select - could be an image, SVG, icon font,
 * etc. or the arrow could just baked into the bg image on the select. */
.custom-select::after {
 content: " ";
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 1em;
 z-index: 2;
 /* These hacks make the select behind the arrow clickable in some browsers */
 pointer-events: none;
 display: none;
}

.custom-select::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 7px solid #666;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

@supports ( -webkit-appearance: none ) or ( appearance: none )
 /* Firefox <= 34 has a false positive on @supports( -moz-appearance: none )
  * @supports ( mask-type: alpha ) is Firefox 35+
  */
 or ( ( -moz-appearance: none ) and ( mask-type: alpha ) ) {
 
 /* Show custom arrow */
 .custom-select::after {
  display: block;
 }

 /* Remove select styling */
 .custom-select select {
  padding-right: 2em; /* Match-01 */
  /* inside @supports so that iOS <= 8 display the native arrow */
  background: none; /* Match-04 */
  /* inside @supports so that Android <= 4.3 display the native arrow */
  border: 1px solid transparent; /* Match-05 */

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
 }
 .custom-select select:focus {
  border-color: #aaa; /* Match-03 */
 }
}

.custom-select {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select">
  <select id="userChannelId" name="userChannelId">
    <option value="">resh resh reshadreshadreshadreshadreshad resh</option>
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Celect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Delect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Felect ---</option>
    <option value="">--- Gelect ---</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this does *not* style the options list in any way, leaving that to the default browser styling. I don't think that is what is desired here.

Comment: You can easily style the option tag with CSS. I just tried and I was able to change the font-size, background-color, etc. Actually, the OP did the same thing, they used an options list and styled it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a javascript alternative using substring that would also append an ellipsis (the 3 ...) to indicate this there is more to this value than is being displayed. You can change the range to whatever you like, I just set it to 20 characters.

```
   $('.styled-select div').each(function() {
       var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
       var value = $container.find('select option:selected').text();
       value = value.substring(0, 20) + '...';
       $(this).html(value);
   });
```

Comment: Downvoter care to share why? OP is already doing work in Javascript in order to even populate his field. Why not just take care of this when populating the field instead of using hackish CSS to accomplish the same thing? edit: eh actually Scott's answer is pretty good compared to the others :]